# Unable to mount USB on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, usb

Gettinf following error while mounting 64GB Pendrive on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/atish/C3F1-ADB2: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/atish/C3F1-ADB2"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
    stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.0.1
    '
    stderr: `ERROR: invalid VBR checksum 0x274dfc79 (expected 0xd71ce9f1).
    '
```

Comment: There are only two possibilities:  either it is corrupted or it uses a different filesystem.  Did you try `fsck /dev/sdb1` to see what it reports?

Comment: You can also use `fdisk /dev/sdb -l` to see all the partitions involved...

Comment: What do you see if you run the following simple sequence: `mkdir -p /mnt/mypen; mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mypen`? What do you see when running: `dmesg | tail -n 10` after running the aforementioned sequence?